# Is Weak self required while fetching notification settings of the app

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, unusernotificationcenter, swift-block

I'm querying notification settings value but I wonder whether `[weak self]` is necessary.

Someone kindly clarify:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { [weak self] appsettings in
    var mybool = false
    if appsettings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
        mybool = true
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        self?.vu.isEnabled = mybool
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intent of the `[weak self]` capture list was to prevent a strong reference cycle, then, no, that is not necessary. This `getNotificationSettings` closure is called asynchronously and its closure (and anything captured by it) is quickly released, so any strong references introduced by the closure are quickly resolved.

If, however, you used `[weak self]` to avoid unnecessarily keeping a strong reference while the asynchronous task is running (e.g., in the unlikely case that `self` is dismissed before this closure runs), then, yes, the `weak` reference is prudent. There is no point in keeping a strong reference if the sole purpose of the closure is to update a control that may no longer be visible.

One could argue that the `[weak self]` is also prudent because one can glance at the code and immediately determine that no strong reference cycle is introduced. You do not have to waste any time reasoning about the notification center API; you immediately see that there is no strong reference cycle risk. Any time you can reason about your code at a glance, that is a good thing.

In short, the `[weak self]` capture list is not necessary, but is prudent.

---

Two unrelated observations:

1. I would eliminate the `[self]` capture list in the dispatch to the main queue. The [whole idea](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0269-implicit-self-explicit-capture.md) of the `[self]` capture list is to allow implicit `self` references inside the closure now that the intent to use `self` has been declared.

   But this is inside the `[weak self]` closure of `getNotificationSettings`, and you are using the `self?.` optional chaining syntax, anyway. The `[self]` capture list not only moot, but only sends contradictory messages to future readers of your code. I would remove `[self]` capture for the dispatch to the main queue.
2. If your question about eliminating the `[weak self]` capture list is motivated by an intent to simplify the code, I would keep the `weak` capture, but simplify the rest:

   ```swift
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { [weak self] settings in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self?.vu.isEnabled = settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. One quick question if notification access was never requested .. what would be the authorisationStatus ?

Comment: [`.notDetermined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationstatus)